# Database audit trigger for username

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm using a piece of code in a database audit trigger but depending on how many people are using the database at a given time, the code can return an unexpected value.

```
-- set username
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
           SET @UserName = (SELECT Top 1 UserName FROM inserted)
   ELSE
           SET @UserName = (SELECT Top 1 UserName FROM inserted)
ELSE
   SET @UserName = (SELECT Top 1 UserName FROM deleted)
```

In some cases this is right and the expected username is being recorded. But it seems if another user also updates the database a fraction later than the first, then their username is being recorded instead.

System_User, User_Name and Current_User all return the iis system used by the website which is used to access the databases. Is there a way to amend this code so that the actual username is captured? The table being updated will always have a UserName column but not sure how to capture that in the trigger.

Comment: that trigger code is completely messed up

Comment: For clarity you should have begin and end for each if.  You need an order by on your top 1 selects or you could get anything back and your inner IF does the same thing under both conditions.  Suggest you refactor your trigger, experiment a little and come back if you have issues.

Comment: Triggers fire once per operation, not once per row. As such you are getting a UserName from one of the two virtual tables but you have no idea which one. And to what end? You should be processing whatever it is you are doing for the entire set, not a scalar value. And what is the point of the nested IF? Both paths do the exact same thing!!

Comment: And no, the database has no way of knowing the username of the person logged into the application unless you send that information to the sql server. Since you are using a single database user that will always be the value in any of the ways you find the user, because it is always the same user on the database side.

Comment: If the process that you are looking at will always only update username to the same value whether it is on one row or on multiple rows, then the Top 1 is okay, although weird. But remember that triggers fire for all processes, not just one, and you may end up with incorrect results from an inadvertent trigger activation.  Also, you can get rid of your `deleted` table check after checking for rows in `inserted`, since you only select from `inserted` in that case.

Comment: Also, looking at the code above, there should never be a case where a second userName is accessed. Triggers fire once per action (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE). To get a second Username from the code above, you would have to be batching insert/update/deletes, somewhere in the input code

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies with whatever logic is used to set the column UserName in the associated table. If that logic were correct (and we can only assume that you not verified that part), your code should work perfectly.

You do have one flaw which is common to trigger writing. Your logic assumes that at least one row was affected by the triggering DML statement. It is entirely possible for zero rows to be affected - the trigger will still execute in such cases. Be certain your logic accounts for that situation correctly.